# Is there a way to wait for a function to load on page load in react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm developing a social network app and I'm trying to load the comments under each post. I've tried using async functions and the useEffect hook but it's not working. Here is the code I've tried

```
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

    // get all comments for the current post
    const getComments = () => {
        async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            await db.collection('posts')
            .doc(postId)
            .collection('comments')
            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                setComments(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
                console.log('Comments', snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
            }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    }

  // load the current user, post ID and comments upon opening the screen
  useEffect(() => {
    getComments();
    getUser();
    getPostId();
  }, []);
```

The comments load in the console but do not get displayed unless I refresh the page while on it. I'm displaying them like so:

```
<View>
    {comments.map((comments, index) => (
      <Comment comment={comments} key={index} />
    ))}
</View>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. `comments.map((comments, index) => (` should be `comments.map((comment, index) => (`

Comment: `<Comment comment={comments} key={index} />` is expecting a comment but got a list of comments instead

Comment: @adamcoakley did you tried return statement with map? if not please try.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the async function inside getComments

```
  const getComments = () => {
    (async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await db.collection('posts')
        .doc(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setComments(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
            console.log('Comments', snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
        }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})()
}
```

or you can also remove the function inside getComments and change the getComments function to async

```
  const getComments = async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await db.collection('posts')
        .doc(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setComments(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
            console.log('Comments', snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
        }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```